# max_execution_time - 3 different values in php.ini, phpinfo and script error

Tags: php, apache

I have the strangest situation with my PHP installation on MacOS.

I had a PHP script throw an error saying `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`. So I thought, no worries, I'll just change it in php.ini.

I called `phpinfo()` to find the `php.ini` file, but `phpinfo()` says that `max_execution_time = 30`. So why did the error say it's 60 seconds? Further more, phpinfo() said that the `Loaded Configuration File` is `/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini`.

So I opened the terminal, tried editing this file with vim and changed `max_execution_time` to 120 just as a test. Then I restarted the server just to be safe, but low and behold, `phpinfo()` still says that `max_execution_time` is 30, and the error log still says `exceeded execution time of 60`, and the value in the file I edited is still 120.

What gives? How are there 3 different values in play here, even though everything seemingly points to the same config file?

I tried doing `php --ini` in the terminal and I got the same information that's in phpinfo regarding the location of the php.ini file.

This is the script in question, it iterates through a directory of CSVs and turns their content into arrays.

```
$files = scandir($dir);
   foreach($files as $file){
        //only CSV files
        if(substr($file,-4) == ".csv"){
                $ret = [];
                if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE) {
                    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){
                    if($data[0] != "Date")
                        $ret[] = [
                            'date' => $data[0],
                            'value' => $data[4]
                        ];
                    }
                    fclose($handle);
                    //array handling goes here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What server did you restart? Maybe php is running in another server? Apache versus fastCGI maybe?

Comment: I restarted Apache, I never started any other servers, at least as far as I know.

Comment: Are you sure the CLI version is the same as the fpm/apache version? Doing "php -i | grep 'php.ini'" in CLI will return the php.ini used by the CLI not the browser. So make sure you are using the php.ini file that is given when outputting phpinfo() in the browser. Once you have saved your php.ini file., validate using phpinfo(). If it is still not working, then look for "ini_set" calls in the code, there may be a call overriding the php.ini configuration.

Comment: What does CLI matter? the script runs in the browser, and phpinfo runs in the browser. Also I did a search for all php.ini files on the computer, there's 2: the one mentioned above and one in Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc - I now set that one to 600 as a test, but nothing changes. The error still says 60, phpinfo still says 30. I don't understand anything anymore.

Comment: I tried doing homebrew upgrade, now it says something about PHP 7.2.7 even though phpinfo says PHP 7.2.0beta3. Running the CLI command you said doesn't seem to return anything telling, is there anything I'm looking for specifically?

Comment: I've added the full current content of the script to the question.

Comment: How about you put `ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');` at the beginning of that script … and figure out how you messed up your local PHP setup later :-)

Comment: Haha I guess that's always an option but the config insanity is bugging me too much :)